# C++ class changing what "*this" refers to

Tags: c++, class, vector, this, variable-assignment

I have a class "foo" which contains a member vector which holds elements of type "foo". This class has a method called "make", which creates "foo" objects and appends them to the vector. I also provide a method for navigating the "foo" object and it's "foo" vector elements called "get".

I would like to re-assign what "this" refers to on any "foo" object to point to a foo object within it's vector. I would like to give the code this functionality as a way to more efficiently navigate and keep track of foo objects without having to bind references to specific "foo" members. I am attempting to do this through a method called "setAsNode" which reassigns what "*this" is.

Here's some example code I mocked up which I believe gets my point across:

```
struct foo{
    foo(const std::string &r):s(r){}
    foo& make(const std::string &r){children.push_back(test(r)); children.back().originalNode = originalNode; return children.back();}
    foo& setAsNode(){*originalNode = *this; return *originalNode;}
    foo& get(int i){return children.at(i);}
private:
    std::vector<foo> children;
    std::string s = "someData";
    foo *originalNode = this;
};
```

and a practical example of how this would function:

```
foo f1("test1");
f1.make("test2").make("test3");//pushes a new foo element back to the vector in f1 and pushes a new foo element back to it's vector
f1.get(0).get(0);//refers to the deepest nested object we just made above, cumbersome to type especially if the nesting is deep
f1.get(0).get(0).setAsNode();//this is where the error occurs, the desired effect is to make f1 the same object as denoted by f1.get(0).get(0);

foo& f2 = f1.get(0).get(0);//f2 would be equivalent to what I want the above code to reset f1 to be (or at least how I'd like it to act)
```

I realize I'm probably implementing some very bad programming practices such as using references instead of pointers for returning "foo" objects, but I honestly do not know how to correctly structure a program such as this, or how a best practice version of this program would look/work. Bonus points for whoever can  show me the "right" way of doing things.

Back to the real question though: how would I make something like this, specifically the "setAsNode" method, actually work? Also, why doesn't the code in my example work? Note, it compiles fine, just crashes upon running.

Comment: If you use containers of `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead, you can be assured that the address of each `T` is unchanged. Only the `unique_ptr` is moved around. Alternatively, you may want to consider using containers with more favorable reference invalidation policies. For example, `std::list` only invalidates references when the element in question is removed from the list.

Comment: To directly answer the question in the title, there is no way of making `this` point to another instance. At best, you can invoke a method of another instance, where that `this` will be different then the `this` from the previous context.

Comment: I don't understand why you need what you claim you need. If you remove the `originalNode` and `setAsNode` stuff, almost everything in your example works fine.

Comment: In order to understand what you really need: what's wrong with just writing `f1 = f1.get(0).get(0);`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes that's exactly the functionality I'm trying to capture, but even attempting to run the code you suggested results in a crash. Also, I don't technically "need" what I claim I need, I was just experimenting with code, seeing what I could accomplish, came up with this thought experiment and would like to know why it behaves as it does and if there's a correct way to make it to begin with.

Comment: @SiracleFox I suspect that the problem is that when you preform that assignment that Martinho suggest you will be replacing `foo.children` with `foo.children[0].children[0].children`. When you do this, `foo.children`'s previous value is  getting replaced, as such all of it's elements are destroyed, including the element you are trying to copy from. You would have to implement assignment operators yourself, move out the value to be copied over and then preform the assignment from that moved object.

Comment: @François is right. I overlooked that. But... what's actually wrong with `foo& f2 = f1.get(0).get(0);`? You comment says it does what you want, but it doesn't explain why you don't want to use that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I could use that if I really wanted to, but I was more interested in experimenting with reassigning what the original object refers to. Simply a thought experiment and coding practice.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ah, that makes sense! I was thinking something along those lines might be happening, but wasn't sure as to the specific order that objects were being assigned/destroyed. To reiterate on your last comment though, it is always 100% impossible to reassign what "this" points to? would that make this idea of using the "setAsNode" method entirely impossible?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don' tbelieve *originalNode = *this would be equivalent to *this = *this because the two "this"s correspond to two different foo objects. I simply wanted the original foo object (f1) to be equal to f1.get(0).get(0), which I thought might be possible to accomplish through reassigning "*this".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I do understand that the objects foo and foo.get(0).get(0) are different objects and thus have different "this"s referring to them, and that "this"s do not cascade. The setAsNode() method is supposed to reassign the original foo object's "this" to refer to foo.get(0).get(0)'s "this", thus (I think) making the original foo object equal to the same as foo.get(0).get(0)'s object, essentially assigning foo to be foo.get(0).get(0), which is (in my opinion) completely synonymous to Fernandes' idea of saying f1 = f1.get(0).get(0);

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux originalNode does not point to foo.get(0).get(0), but does, in fact, point to the original foo object, as I have tested in my code by cout-ing the memory locations. It's in the make method that originalNode is re-assigned to be pointing to foo.

Comment: @SiracleFox I've misread your `make` method, and I'll retract my irrelevant comments. The problem then is that you are deleting the leaf node while you are executing one of it's methods. See the 6th comment from the top. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yea, the second you mentioned that made everything click for me! That being said, is there any way to keep the vector in the original foo around long enough for the assignment to take place without destroying the object that's assigning to it? perhaps making the vector with std::shared_ptr? Or.. maybe declaring the vector to be on the heap and deleting the vector with foo's destructor? what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the call to `foo.get(0).get(0).setAsNode()` will attempt to copy the value of `foo.get(0).get(0)` to `foo`. In the process, `foo.children` will be assigned a new value, causing the vector to clear it's previous elements leading to the destruction of `foo.get(0).get(0)`. This means that `this` has been destroyed and that the pointer can't be used. However, this is happening during an assignment operation which us currently using `this`. To solve this, you must insure that the value being copied persists long enough to be copied. The intuitive solution might be to copy the value to assign before assigning it.

```
foo& setAsNode() { 
    auto this_copy = *this;
    *originalNode = std::move(this_copy); 
    return *originalNode; 
}
```

This will work, you still have to be careful never to use `this` after the assignment to `*originalNode`. Another solution would be to take control of `originalNode`'s children vector before preforming the assignment. In this version `this` remains valid until the method returns but if the following assignment throws an exception your tree will be left in an invalid state.

```
foo& setAsNode() { 
    auto original_vect = std::move(originalNode->children);
    *originalNode = *this;
    return *originalNode; 
}
```

All in all, I would be wary of a design that calls for objects to commit suicide. It implies object controls their own ownership or that ownership responsibilities are otherwise cyclical.

Answer (score 2):

The c++ way (and arguably only correct way) is to *separate concerns*.

A foo is not (or should not be) a foo-finder. It should do foo-things, not foo-navigation things.

Make a new class to act as the cursor or iterator of your foo.

Here is a slightly expanded version, in which the foo_cursor remembers its journey through the foo stack. Probably overkill for your problem but it demonstrates the principle of separating foo-navigation logic from foo-implementation logic.

The more you do this, the easier your programs will be to write, debug and maintain.

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>


struct foo{
    foo(const std::string &r)
        : children()
        , s(r)
    {}

    foo& make(const std::string &r)
    {
        children.emplace_back(r);
        return children.back();
    }

    foo& get(int i)
    {
        return children.at(i);
    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }


private:

    std::vector<foo> children;
    std::string s = "someData";
};

struct foo_cursor
{
    foo_cursor(foo& f)
        : current_(std::addressof(f))
    {}

    foo_cursor& down(int i)
    {
        history_.push(current_);
        current_ = std::addressof(current_->get(i));
        return *this;
    }

    foo_cursor& up() {
        if (history_.empty()) {
            throw std::logic_error("went up too far");
        }
        else {
            current_ = history_.top();
            history_.pop();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    foo* operator->() const {
        return current_;
    }

private:
    foo* current_;
    std::stack<foo*> history_;
};


int main()
{
    foo f("a");
    f.make("b").make("c");

    auto fc = foo_cursor(f);
    fc.down(0).down(0)->print();
    fc.up()->print();
    fc.up()->print();
}
```

expected output:

```
c
b
a
```